# What is the latest GSO capacity for the Russian heavy launch-vehicle Proton-M?

Tags: rockets, payload, proton-m

Proton started with Proton-K (Proton-Zond) to Proton-M and has now grown to major phases 1-4 and enhanced Block-Dm and Briz-M.

What is the latest geostationary orbit (GSO) capacity? I could not find it anywhere. Will there be some more work done (before they are being gradually replaced by Angara A5), or is it that the old railroad has it limits?

Found [Space Launch Report](http://spacelaunchreport.com/proton.html) but it does not provide easy detail. [RussianSpaceWeb.com](http://russianspaceweb.com/proton-m.html) is pretty close. And [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/proton_(rocket_family)).

Comment: 19 years is a long time - maybe it would be better to ask if upgrades to the Proton-M are planned now. Upgrades don't necessarily mean that the rocket becomes heavier, so i don't think the load the railroad can bear is relevant - and at any rate, they could always find another way to deliver the rocket.

Comment: Its more about length of rocket "_x_" limit than weight its very large distance from moscow to baiknour.

Comment: Upgrades don't necessarily mean a rocket becomes longer either, and there are still other solutions. If you want to know if Russian companies limit the size or mass of their rockets to fit the railroad, that should be a separate question.

Answer (score 5):

Spaceflight101 gives the direct geostationary orbit payload capacity as 3500kg using the Briz-M stage. http://spaceflight101.com/spacerockets/proton-m-briz-m/

Wikipedia lists it as 3250kg, referring to a 2009 mission planner's guide.

Answer (score 2):

These are the fresh ideas as published by ILS:

[Proton Medium / Proton Light](http://www.ilslaunch.com/sites/default/files/pdf/Proton_Variant_Brochure_Mech.pdf)

[Expanded Proton Line: Proton Medium & Proton Light](http://www.ilslaunch.com/sites/default/files/2-Press%20Conference%20-%20ENG.PDF)

The main development is in the removal of the second stage and the reduction of the first stage.

Comment: It's a 50 year old launcher. Has this kind of evolution of the Proton into a same generation family with different payload capabilities been considered before, or why not?